# dynamic table layout table row content is not working

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout

Hi in the below code I am implementing dynamic table layout. dynamically added table row names also added dynamically.

trying adding the content to the rows.but it is throwing an exception array index out of bound exception.

can any one help me where i did the mistake

```
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
```

Code

```
 String productValues = listSalesStageOpportunity.get(position).getProductValue();
TableLayout stk = (TableLayout) customView.findViewById(R.id.tables);
        TableRow tbrow0 = new TableRow(getContext());
        TextView tv0 = new TextView(getContext());
        tv0.setText(" Sl.No ");
        tv0.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tbrow0.addView(tv0);
        TextView tv1 = new TextView(getContext());
        tv1.setText(" Item Name ");
        tv1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tbrow0.addView(tv1);
        TextView tv2 = new TextView(getContext());
        tv2.setText(" Unit Price ");
        tv2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tbrow0.addView(tv2);
        TextView tv3 = new TextView(getContext());
        tv3.setText(" Total ");
        tv3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tbrow0.addView(tv3);
        stk.addView(tbrow0);
        for (int i = 0; i < productValues.length(); i++) {
            TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(getContext());
            TextView t1v = new TextView(getContext());
            String[] namesList = productValues.split(",");
            t1v.setText(namesList[i]);//error
            t1v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            t1v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbrow.addView(t1v);
stk.addView(tbrow);
        }
```

Comment: The split method returned an array with length 3 and you are trying to access the e 4th element, which doesn't exist. Check that all "productValues" are being properly split and generating an array with 4 items in it.

Comment: @InkArcher productValues contains 3 items like falco,cs30,bs these are the elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ProductValues.length() is returning an unreachable value** of 4 (out of 13).

If there are only 3 items (falco,cs30,bs) the max value for *i* is 2, but *i* is equals to 3 according the exception.

If productValues = "falco,cs30,bs". The call productValues.length() returns 13. You array does not have 13 items.

you should move the split method up, before the for loop, and use its result as the loop iterator.

```
String[] namesList = productValues.split(",");
for (int i = 0; i < namesList.length(); i++) 
{
        TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(getContext());
        TextView t1v = new TextView(getContext());
        t1v.setText(namesList[i]);
        t1v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        t1v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tbrow.addView(t1v);
        stk.addView(tbrow);
}
```

Comment: I have one doubt

Comment: what would that question be?

Comment: in the same way i have a another list